# How to render a component in a different page when click on a link in a table row in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner in ReactJs, and I have a `ProjectsList` component which includes an html table. One of its columns is a link which when clicked it must navigate to a different page rendering a `ProjectInfo` component.

But, what happens is that the component is rendered in the same page of `ProjectsList` component at the end of the table.
`ProjectsList` component is rendered when clicked on a link `Show Projects` in `Projects` component.

**Projects.component.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NewProject from "../NewProject/NewProject.component";
import ProjectsList from "../ProjectsList/ProjectsList.component";
import "./Projects.css";

export default class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="projects-dashboard">
        <nav className="nav-up">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={"/dashboard/projects/add"}>add project</Link>
            </li>

            <li>
              <Link to={"/dashboard/projects/list"}>show projects</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
          <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/add"} component={NewProject} />
          <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/list"} component={ProjectsList} />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ProjectsList.component.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./ProjectsList.css";
import ProjectInfo from "../ProjectInfo/ProjectInfo.component";

export default class ProjectsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allProject: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchAllProjects();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
  }

  fetchAllProjects = () => {
    axios.get("/api/projects").then(res => {
      this.setState({ allProject: res.data }, () => { console.log(this.state.allProject); });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const projects = this.state.allProject.map(project => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{project.id}</td>
          <td>{project.title}</td>
          <td>{project.organization_name}</td>
          <td className="project-options">
            <Link to={`/dashboard/projects/list/${project.id}`}>
              <i className="far fa-eye" /> show
            </Link>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <table class="projects-list-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <h1>Project ID</h1>
              </th>
              <th>
                <h1>Project Name</h1>
              </th>
              <th>
                <h1>Organization Name</h1>
              </th>
              <th>
                <h1>Options</h1>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{projects}</tbody>
        </table>
        <main>
          <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/list/:id"} component={ProjectInfo} />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ProjectInfo.component.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./ProjectInfo.css";

export default class ProjectInfo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Project Info Component</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React router includes those components to the specified section where the Route tag is. For instance:

```
<section>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <Route path={"/random/path"} component={MyComponent} />
</section>
```

will return

```
<section>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <MyComponent />
</section>
```

to get around this you need to add it to the same level of routing as your PrjectList route.

so change this

```
<main>
  <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/add"} component={NewProject} />
  <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/list"} component={ProjectsList} />
</main>
```

to

```
<main>
  <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/add"} component={NewProject} />
  <Route exact path={"/dashboard/projects/list"} component={ProjectsList} />
  <Route exact path={"/dashboard/projects/list/:id"} component={ProjectInfo} />
</main>
```

**EDIT**

The last route should not have the exact tag on

```
<main>
  <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/add"} component={NewProject} />
  <Route exact path={"/dashboard/projects/list"} component={ProjectsList} />
  <Route path={"/dashboard/projects/list/:id"} component={ProjectInfo} />
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclusively render a component, meaning that you want to only render one specific component (which in you case is `ProjectInfo`) when you click on the link in the table, and in this case you don't want to render the `Projects` component, you need to use `Switch` within the router.

From the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch)

> ### **`<Switch>`**
>
> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that
>   matches the location.
>
> How is this different than just using a bunch of `<Route>`s?
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In
>   contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders
>   inclusively.
>
> Consider this code:
>
> ```
> <Route path="/about" component={About}/> 
> <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
> <Route component={NoMatch}/>
> ```
>
> If the URL is /about, then `<About>`, `<User>`, and `<NoMatch>` will all
>   render because they all match the path. This is by design, allowing us
>   to compose `<Route>`s into our apps in many ways, like sidebars and
>   breadcrumbs, bootstrap tabs, etc.

So, change your `Projects` component to something like this (You are already importing Switch so no need to import it again):

```
<main>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/dashboard/projects/add"} component={NewProject} />
    <Route exact path={"/dashboard/projects/list"} component={ProjectsList} />
  </Switch>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried this but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: @Shatha I forgot to add the exact prop to the route, but it should work. I see you already found another solution and I'm glad you solved your problem. Switch is useful in most cases so maybe if you run into another problem in a different situation, don't forget to try this approach as well.

Comment: @ c-chavez Actually I appreciate it a lot. I used it in different case and it worked fine.